# A name for the property $ \| x \star y \| = \| x \| \| y \| $.

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology, normed-spaces

Suppose that $ \star: V^2 \to V $ is some binary operation on a vector space $ V $. Should it hold, is there a name for the following property?
$$
\forall x,y \in V: \quad
\| x \star y \| = \| x \| \| y \|.
$$

Comment: Well, if that holds for all $x,y$ and $\star$ is bilinear, then $\star$ makes $V$ into an algebra, though it actually does quite a bit more, since an algebra only needs $\leq$ rather than $=$. In general you might call it multiplicativity, though I don't think you will find that much in the way of references in this direction.

Comment: You can call it multiplicativity of the norm.

Comment: Thanks both, wasn't sure about terminology. I will take a look into algebras!

Comment: @pbs: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function

Comment: @tampis of course I should have remembered that from Number Theory !

Comment: That will work, as long as you're content to call $\star$ "multiplication".

Comment: You may want to have a look at tensor products and cross norms as well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_tensor_product.

Comment: I've heard submultiplicative in the case of matrix norms. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Comment: @mgn: Cross-norms are, by definition, multiplicative on elementary tensors, but this property does not necessarily extend to the entire tensor product.

Comment: sure, this is why I wrote "you may want to have a look", because it is relevant up to some extent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $ \Bbb{F} $ denote the base field of $ V $. If we assume that $ \star $ is a binary operation on $ V $ that turns $ V $ into an $ \Bbb{F} $-algebra, i.e.,

- **Left distributivity:** $ x \star (y + z) = x \star y + x \star z $ for every $ x,y,z \in V $,
- **Right distributivity:** $ (x + y) \star z = x \star z + y \star z $ for every $ x,y,z \in V $, and
- **Compatibility with scalar multiplication:** $ \lambda \cdot (x \star y) = (\lambda \cdot x) \star y = x \star (\lambda \cdot y) $ for every $ \lambda \in \Bbb{F} $ and every $ x,y \in V $,

then we call $ \| \cdot \| $ a **multiplicative norm** for $ \star $.

**Note:** As we are discussing norms here, we necessarily assume that $ \Bbb{F} \in \{ \Bbb{R},\Bbb{C} \} $.

It turns out that if $ V $ is a *unital* $ \Bbb{R} $-algebra having a multiplicative norm, then by [a result of Urbanik and Wright](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1960-011-06/S0002-9939-1960-0120264-6/S0002-9939-1960-0120264-6.pdf), $ V $ is isomorphic to one of the following four normed $ \Bbb{R} $-algebras:

- $ \Bbb{R} $ (the real field).
- $ \Bbb{C} $ (the complex field).
- $ \Bbb{H} $ (the quaternions).
- $ \Bbb{O} $ (the octonions).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer ! When you say "we necessarily assume..." does that mean that if $\mathbb{F}\not\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$ then we cannot call $\|\cdot\|$ a norm, so that we must use some other symbol, say $| \cdot |$ and call it something other than a "norm", much like we use the absolute notation for "valuations", for example. And if so, does this $|\cdot |$ have a name in this context ?

Comment: @picasso: Hi. Yes, you’re right. By definition, a normed vector space must be a vector space over $ \Bbb{R} $ or $ \Bbb{C} $. I don’t have a ready answer to your second question, however.