# Reference for multiplicative norms

Tags: reference-request, normed-spaces

Does anyone know of a book which deals with multiplicative norms, e.g. $N( x\circ y)=N( x)N( y)$ ? Any help appreciated. A Google search showed up a few links, but I was hoping for an intermediate text book which had a section or chapter on such norms.

**EDIT**

Let $ \circ: V^2 \to V $ be some binary operation on a vector space $ V $.

Also related to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288528/a-name-for-the-property-x-star-y-x-y).

Comment: What is $\circ$?

Comment: @gerw It's some binary operation $ \circ: V^2 \to V $ on some vector space $ V $.

Comment: No pressure to answer, but I'd be curious to know how and where such things arise. I think it is more typical to find that $\|x \circ y \| \leq \|x \| \|y \|$.

Comment: I think that's called a sub-multiplicative norm; not 100% sure though.

Comment: @goblin Any finite field extension $K \subset L$ comes with such a norm called the field norm (here we view $L$ as a $K$-vector space and the multiplication of $L$ as the additional operation).

Comment: @MarcPaul, interesting! So that seems to explain where absolute values come from. It would probably be better to call this "the absolute value of $x \in L$ with respect to $K$" or something like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the realm of **multiplicative calculus**$-$one of the ininitely many non-Newtonian calculi. The fundamentals were introduced by [Grossman and Katz (1972)](https://books.google.de/books?id=RLuJmE5y8pYC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Multiplicative spaces with multiplicative norms and metrics are discussed by [Bashirov et al (2008)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X07003824) and [Çakmak and Başar (2012)](http://www.journalofinequalitiesandapplications.com/content/2012/1/228); but I am not aware of a book in which these concepts are discussed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I own a copy of Grossman and Katz (1972) - fascinating stuff !

Comment: Why are these "non-classical calculi" called "non-Newtonian"? This to me seems a bit unfortunate given that Leibniz is completely left out here. Smells a bit like an Anglo-Saxon bias, not?

Comment: @gwr Indeed, it is a bias. But once the term was coined (by Grossman and Katz), it was indiscriminately assumed by other authors. But history takes revenge: Jane Grossman, the wife of Michael Grossman, is hardly mentioned anywhere, even though she also contributed to the topic.

Comment: Thanks for that note. One might also add that there are so little "fluxions" around these days... :)