# What Algebra law is this called: $|\alpha \beta| \le |\alpha| |\beta|$ for complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to remember the name of this law in complex number algebra:

$$|\alpha \beta| \le |\alpha| |\beta|$$

Where:

$$\alpha = Re\{\alpha\}+ i \ Im\{\alpha\}$$
$$\beta  = Re\{\beta\}+ i \ Im\{\beta\}$$

Comment: It is not an Algebra law, but just an equation: $|zw|=|z||w|$ for complex $z,w$. It is sometimes called "norm", and it is multiplicative. A proof is given [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Complex_Modulus_of_Product_of_Complex_Numbers).

Comment: its a law because I started with the magnitude formed by the product of two complex numbers and then inferred that its less than  or equal to the magnitude of each complex number individually and then multiplied together....  and this equation always holds.... its never less than...always greater-than or equal-to

Comment: could be a **linear algebra** property as well... I was just trying to avoid dealing with dot products...so I was looking for the **complex algebra** law name to get around thinking about dot products...

Comment: There are no dot products here anyway. Just complex numbers and their absolute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For complex this is an immediate consequence of $|z|^2=z\bar z$ and associative property of multiplication.

Indeed $|ab|^2=(ab)(\overline{ab})=ab\bar a\bar b=(a\bar a)(b\bar b)=|a|^2|b|^2$

And since $|\cdot|$ is positive then we can get rid of squares.

For a more general result, you may be interested in this post:

[A name for the property $ \| x \star y \| = \| x \| \| y \| $.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288528/a-name-for-the-property-x-star-y-x-y?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: what's the meaning of the "double absolute value braces" is that just a fancy absolute value brace or does it have special meaning?  also, is the "star" implicit if you don't write it in a complex algebra equation?

Comment: This is used for a **norm** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics), this is a multidimensional extension of absolute value. The star here, just represent any binary operation similar to a dot product.

Comment: thanks... i guess my math book is just lax about calling norms as absolute values...

Comment: That's interesting... so you only need the inequality if we are dealing with vectors? instead of scalar complex number? its actually exactly equal when dealing with scalar numbers.  that's actually, a little bit confusing because the book was saying that complex numbers are vectors of real and imaginary numbers

Answer (score 1):

You not only have $\vert \alpha \beta \vert \le \vert \alpha \vert \vert \beta \vert$ but even $\vert \alpha \beta \vert = \vert \alpha \vert \vert \beta \vert$.

**The complex modulus is multiplicative**

Comment: it only equals if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are scalars, or they have the same complex phase angle.

Comment: @MrCasuality You’re confusing sum and multiplication.